# Mockito Test for Spring NamedJDBC Template

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, jdbctemplate

I am trying to figure out mickito test for Named Jdbc Template but unable to do so. I did googling but did not find any accurate result. Below is example Code.

Student.class

```
@Data
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Student(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        id = rs.getInt("id");
        name = rs.getString("name");
        address = rs.getString("address");
    }
}
```

Student class takes ResultSet argument in constructor and mapped all column to variable .

StudentService.class

```
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("namedJdbcTemplate")
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    public Student gerStudent(String id) {
        Student student;
        String selectStudent = "select id , name ,address from student where id=:id";
        MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        mapSqlParameterSource.addValue(id, "id");
        student = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(selectStudent, mapSqlParameterSource, resultSet -> {
            Student response = new Student(resultSet);
            return response;
        });

        return student;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help on Mockito Test for below line of code?

```
student = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(selectStudent, mapSqlParameterSource, resultSet -> {
                Student response = new Student(resultSet);
                return response;
            });
```

Comment: How are you initializing `namedParameterJdbcTemplate`? I have to mock your `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` object.

Comment: @iamanbansal I am auto-wiring from XML bean. I just updated code in question. Thanks.

Comment: @Shashi if you do not include **all details** in your code you will receive **incomplete answers**. Removed my own one